# How to connect to AWS ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have successfully created ECS cluster (EC2 Linux + Networking). Is it possible to login to the cluster to perform some administrative tasks? I have not deployed any containers or tasks to it yet. I can’t find any hints for it in AWS console or AWS documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "cluster" is just a logical grouping of resources. The "cluster" itself isn't a server you can log into or anything. You would perform actions on the cluster via the AWS console or the AWS API. You can connect to the EC2 servers managed by the ECS cluster individually. You would do that via the standard `ssh` method you would use to connect to any other EC2 Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

ECS will take care most of the administrative works for you.You simply have to deploy and manage your applications on ECS. If you setup ECS correctly, you will never have to connect to instances.
Follow these instructions to deploy your service (docker image): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-service.html

Also you can use Cloudwatch to store container logs, so that you don't have to connect to instances to check the logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html